# Sponge capacity feed-forward

Tags: preimage-resistance, sponge, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Consider Sponge construction where capacity part of state is feed-forward and xor-ed into next state.

${state}_{i+1} = F({{state}_i}^{rate} || {{state}_i}^{capacity}) \oplus (0^{rate} || {{state}_i}^{capacity})$

1. Would there be any security improvement from this?
2. Would it improve preimage and 2nd preimage security?

This seems to be similar to [JH](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/wuhj/research/jh/jh_round3.pdf) mode which claims higher preimage and 2nd preimage security for JH-512 compared to Sponge. However this has not been proven as far as I know. Paper ["Improved Indifferentiability Security Bound for the JH Mode"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/278) says:

> It is somewhat remarkable that despite the absence of generic attacks
> with work-factor significantly lower than $n$ bits, the proven 1st/2nd
> pre-image and indifferentiability bounds for the JH mode are only up
> to $n/2$ bits.

It is also similar to [Hamsi](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-1203.pdf), but Hamsi is overwriting rate. It claims higher preimage security, but no proof.

Comment: The Keccak team said somewhere that what you propose will be just as secure as the standard construction and no more. All it will achieve is a ratchet effect where compromise of state does not allow unwinding backward in time. Some AEAD schemes in fact do this to blind the state to the key. But not every iteration as it would do nothing of note.

Comment: @LightTunnelEnd But it seems Keccak team was more like "our proof still applies". I don't know if bounds are tight. JH mode seems similar and claims higher preimage and 2nd preimage security (JH-512). However, it is not proven as far as I know.